# Can I tell in the portal when an Azure deployment happened?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

When we deploy our App Service from Visual Studio 2015 to Azure we tag the current commit in Git so that we can get back to any of our past deployments.

But I suspect that we forgot to do that when we deployed our current ASP API.

Using the Azure portal how do I tell when the deployment running in one of our app service's deployment slots was made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are use classic portal, you can find the deployment history list in the **DEPLOYMENTS** tab of your app service application. And you can click one of them, click the `REDEPLOY` button at the bottom nav bar to rollback to the specific deployment version.
 [image]

If you are using Azure portal, you also can find the deployment history, by clicking `deployment source` => selecting the specific deployment version=>click `redeploy` button to rollback.
[image]

Comment: Mine's not looking the same :-( Here's the [classic](http://imgur.com/a/yTw1R) and [new](http://imgur.com/a/AsMCD) portal screenshots for me.

Comment: According your screenshots, it seems that you haven't set a source deployment slot yet. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-continous-deployment/ for Continuous Deployment to Azure App Service

Comment: Given that I published to the current deployment slots by clicking 'publish' in VS2015 does that mean I cannot find out via the portal? Should I have set a source deployment slot in the portal first?

Comment: Yes, and you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-continous-deployment/#VSsolution for more info. Otherwise, you can refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/02/06/create-connect-and-publish-using-visual-studio-with-git/ for manually setting up git repository on VS.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using kudu: https://[webappname].scm.azurewebsites.net/ - you can see file timestamps in the console.

Comment: Which file would be the tell-tale for the deployment date?

Comment: I was thinking much more primitively... If you go to the console you can navigate the file system (e.g. /site/wwwroot/default.aspx) and see the timestamp on the file.  That should match what you have in source code control history.  It' won't tell you *when* it was deployed, but will tell you *what* is deployed.  For binaries you could get version info in the console.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking you service you can go to All Settings --> Audit Logs. There you can filter by 'Update website'

Comment: If I put 'update website' in the search box ([here](http://imgur.com/a/GAElX)) I get 'no results to display'